# Content Update Option

Tags: nodes

I'm using Drupal 7. I made a couple of content types and taxonomies. Is there any way to select multiple content in the same content type and modify their fields together?

For instance, I have account type with the fields: `account number`, `test case`, ...

I want to set multiple account contents' test case to the same value.

Note: the test case is just a field with a selection of test case names, sry about the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're coding up test cases -- not really. You could build the nodes programatically with some test account numbers, etc. But, you'd have to do that by hand. There are alot of tutorials for [SimpleTest](http://drupal.org/simpletest-tutorial-drupal7) and [creating nodes](http://drupal.org/node/1388922) in drupal.

If you need a GUI to alter many node fields at once, take a look at [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations).

Comment: actually, the test case is just a field with a selection of test cast names, sry about the confusion